# In HTML5 client-side storage how do you get the value of the key?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I stored a value with a key like this `localStorage[title] = text;` I know I can recall the `text` by doing `var text = localStorage[title]` but how do you get the value of the `title` to insert into the `localStorage` so that the program knows what value to get. Is there any way to loop through the keys in the `localStorage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>[removed `for-in` example]</sub>

The `localStorage` API, allows you to iterate over the keys, we have a [`length`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-length) property, and the [`key`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-key) function.

The `key` function takes an index and returns the name of the key:

```
var key, value;
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  key = localStorage.key(i);
  value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  // use key or value
}
```

Try this example [here](http://jsbin.com/ukolu5/2/edit).

Comment: hmm... I guess I still am a little confused. If I used `var key` will that go through each key and give you the key?

Comment: Here's a problem with the *first* code sample. If you use JavaScript libraries such as Prototype that extend built-in JavaScript objects, you will end up seeing the methods that it added in addition to what you want; it's just another quirk of JavaScript.

Comment: @idealmachine, yes, seems that `localStorage` inherits from `Object.prototype`, (`localStorage instanceof Object; // true`). I don't think PrototypeJS or MooTools extend the `Object.prototype` object, but anyway as a rule of thumb, a `hasOwnProperty` check need to be there... Actually, I think is better to avoid `for-in`, since the API allows you to iterate over the keys..., I'll remove the first sample...

Comment: The `localStorage` API still has problems, for example, collisions between "keys" and API members... [for example...](http://jsbin.com/ukolu5/4/edit) :(

Comment: ah... looking at your example makes it make total sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @PleaseStand - That's not a quirk of JavaScript. That's a quirk of the first hugely popular JS library helping us discover why extending deep-core native JS constructor prototypes like Object and some would argue Function was a really awful idea. Hats off to the prototype guys for being the early DOM API normalizers but stop using it if they never fixed that problem. The hasOwnProperty approach is usually the way to go. I also tend to separate stuff I'm likely to want to iterate as aggregate object literals within objects with getter methods that search, compare, and grab for you.

Comment: @ErikReppen: Do you use jQuery? It is (generally?) pointless for any script using jQuery to perform hasOwnProperty checks because jQuery does not perform them itself. http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#JSLint

Comment: I do, but JQuery uses hasOwnProperty all over the place internally and JQ object methods typically loop automatically when it makes sense to (e.g. '.css' will hit every tag in a multi-tag selection without using 'each') so it's pretty rare that I use the 'each' method. It's not really less verbose than core looping, IMO, and it incurs a lot of avoidable overhead, especially in older browsers where firing the callback function repeatedly will drastically reduce perf.